# <a href > Links only work one way

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, header

I seem to have come across an error within my navigation bar. When I navigate from my "Technologies" page to Home page it works. However when I navigate from the Home Page to the Technologies page nothing happens. Can you explain this error because it honestly doesn't make any sense.

HTML: Home page

```
<body>

<h1 class = "name"><font color = "#3399FF"> Prog-Assist |  </font><font size = "12"> Where Collaboration is Welcomed</font></h1>

<div id = "header">
    <div id = "gradient">
        <div class = "nav">

    <!-- container-fluid gives full width container of whole viewport -->

    <div class = "container-fluid">


    <ul id = "nav" class= "text-left">
        <li><a href = "Main.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href = "Tech.html">Technologies</a></li>
        <li><a href = "#">Programs</a></li>
        <li><a href = "#">Blog</a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul id = "nav" class = "text-right">
        <li><a href = "#"><strong>Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href = "#">Sign In</a></li>
        <li><a href = "#">Contact</strong></a></li>
    </ul>

    </div><!-- end container-fluid-->
        </div><!--end nav-->
    </div>
</div> <!-- end header -->
```

Tech Page:

```
<body>

<h1 class = "name" ><font color = "#3399FF"> Prog-Assist |  </font><font size = "12"> Where Collaboration is Welcomed</font></h1>

<div id = "header">
    <div id = "gradient">
        <div class = "nav">

    <!-- container-fluid gives full width container of whole viewport -->

    <div class = "container-fluid">


    <ul id = "nav" class= "text-left">
        <li><a href = "Main.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href = "Tech.html">Technologies</a></li>
        <li><a href = "#">Programs</a></li>
        <li><a href = "#">Blog</a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul id = "nav" class = "text-right">
        <li><a href = "#"><strong>Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href = "#">Sign In</a></li>
        <li><a href = "#">Contact</strong></a></li>
    </ul>

    </div><!-- end container-fluid-->

        </div><!--end nav-->
    </div>
</div> <!-- end header -->
```

CSS for links:

```
#nav {

list-style: none;

}

.nav a {

text-decoration: none; /*remove underline*/
text-transform: uppercase;
color: #00002E;

}

.nav li {

display: inline;
float: left;
padding: 10px;

}

.text-left {

float: left;
padding-left: 30px;
}
```

My folder with files:

[image]

When I try to inspect element

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some steps to solve this issue:

- lowercase your filenames. Main.html becomes main.html, same for all other html files.
- use proper `<html>` open and closing tags. this is important!
- you might use a `<link>` tag to include your style (stylesheet.css)
- i've add "I'm the Main Page" and a title to show that navigation works
- you might apply the same stuff to your tech.html
- navigation works and css style, too.

File: **main.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Main Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>    
    I'm the Main Page.

    <h1 class = "name">
        <font color = "#3399FF"> Prog-Assist |  </font><font size = "12"> Where Collaboration is Welcomed</font>
    </h1>

    <div id = "header">
        <div id = "gradient">
            <div class = "nav">    
                <!-- container-fluid gives full width container of whole viewport -->    
                <div class = "container-fluid">    
                <ul id = "nav" class= "text-left">
                    <li><a href = "main.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "tech.html">Technologies</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#">Programs</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#">Blog</a></li>
                </ul>    
                <ul id = "nav" class = "text-right">
                    <li><a href = "#"><strong>Sign Up</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#">Sign In</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#">Contact</strong></a></li>
                </ul>    
                </div><!-- end container-fluid-->
            </div><!--end nav-->
        </div>
    </div> <!-- end header -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: let me try to rename the files and i do have the closing tags in my page too

Comment: WOW... I renamed the files all lowercase and now they work... I am not sure what that means but they are fixed XD

Comment: Lots of comments. Easy fix ;) Glad you solved it. Have fun hacking.

Comment: That's strange. On windows, paths should be case insensitive. And OP was using the proper case.

Comment: I see my issue. my IE won't work... but Google Chrome is for connecting my pages @Jens-AndréKoch

Comment: Yes, that's possible. IE often needs a doctype definition to work properly - other browsers are more forgiving and more compatible in rendering things. (What might help: Each browser has a console, where you can see the errors on a page. Just hit F12. It's often that some tags are not closed or a doctype is missing. -- Ah, i see your screenshot now. )

Comment: ya I have the <!DOCTYPE html> from what i know with doctypes. And its the first time i've seen F12. It shows my doctype there.